# Mean app on plesk: backend vs frontend routes

Tags: angular, mean-stack, plesk, plesk-onyx

I am currently working on a MEAN app and I just deployed it on my server which uses Plesk. However, I now face the following situation:

The app is succesfully deployed. Initial call of app works as expected. Routing triggered within Angular itself works as expected.

But I can't call specific frontend routes from my browser, for example:
mydomain.com/costs -> Cannot GET /costs

Wheres the backend routes are working properly:
mydomain.com/api/costs -> Works fine

I understand that my domain is listening on the express server, but how do I achieve that it is using the front end routes?

Comment: For me the backend routes do not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it. I was just listening on my port in express, but not including the absolute path of my angular app:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('App starts on: ' + app.get('port'));
  }
```